# How to do render a database queryset in a Django base template?

Tags: django

I wish to display some queryset across all the pages in my website.

From all indications, the logical thing to do is to include the tagging in the base.html.

Unfortunately, the base.html is not been rendered or called by a url. So I am having tough time doing that.

WHAT I HAVE DONE.
1

1. I made the query in a view that calls reders index.html.
2. Passed the queryset into the context.
3. Extended base.html in my index.html template
4. used template tagging to call the queryset.

It worked well in my local. but after deployment to heroku, it stopped displaying on my index.

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import CompanyProfile, CompanyServices


def index_view(request):
    company_services = CompanyServices.objects.all()
    company_profile = CompanyProfile.objects.all()

    context = {
        'profile': company_profile,
        'services': company_services,
    }

    return render(request, 'webpages/index.html', context=context)
```

base.html snipptet

```
<body>
  <!-- ======= Top Bar ======= -->
  <section id="topbar" class="d-none d-lg-block">
    <div class="container d-flex">
      <div class="contact-info mr-auto">
        <i class="icofont-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:contact@example.com">{{profile.company_email}}</a>
        <i class="icofont-phone"></i> {{profile.company_phone1}}
      </div>
```

How else can I make this work?

Comment: To load data into `base.html`, the cleanest way is to use `context_processors`. Look at [Willem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828493/how-i-do-render-a-queryset-in-a-django-base-template). Context_processor methods can allow you get `request` object and also return **parameters in context** just like the `request` object. **NOTE:** They only work successfully if you're using **render** in your Views